# EventAggregator Helper Generic method

Tags: c#, generics, prism, eventaggregator

Why this gives a compiler error?

```
public class EventAggregationHelper {

    public static SubscriptionToken SubscribeToEvent<T>( IEventAggregator eventAggregator ) where T : EventBase {

        T evt = eventAggregator.GetEvent<T>();
        //T evt = eventAggregator.GetEvent<T>();
        return null;
    }
}
```

The error is:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   CS0310  'T' must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless constructor in order to use it as parameter 'TEventType' in the generic type or method 'IEventAggregator.GetEvent()'    EntitySetGridTWPF   D:\DEVELOPER.NET\Comercial\EntityBookCommon\EntitySetGridTWPF\EventAggregation\EventAggregationHelper.cs    9   Active

on the line:

```
T evt = eventAggregator.GetEvent<T>();
```

I've used this approach for calling other generic methods before and has worked. What has GetEvent so special?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe start with reading and understanding the error you were presented with.

Comment: @kiziu Believe me when I tell you that I try to search information and try too many things before asking in any forum, including this. Sometimes every one has dumb mistakes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`IEventAggregator.GetEvent`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405785%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) has a `new()` constraint, which means that your subscription also needs to add the `new()` constraint and that also needs to be fulfilled by your implementation class `T`, which must have a public parameterless (default) constructor (and must not be abstract.)

```
public static SubscriptionToken SubscribeToEvent<T>
            (IEventAggregator eventAggregator) where T : EventBase, new() {
```

Comment: I added new() also but not when I was having T forced to EventBase, but to PubSubEvent instead, so that must be why it din't worked at first and then I got confused. Thank you very much.